# Restore bathtub enamel?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

Have a bathtub that is abotu 12 yrs old, with a shower and the bottom of the tub seems to have a spot where the enamel is wearing off.  Never seen this happen before.  Probably because I was so poor growing up we didnt have a shower, only a tub LOL

Below is a shot of my tub.  The finish is coming off the drain fixtures also, but my main question is regarding the enamel.

Has anyone done a restoration like whats shown in this video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3U6YseqHoE

[image]

Comment: Does the water drain fully, or does a puddle sit in that spot? It may not be "enamel wear" - it may be water staining from incomplete drainage, and the minerals depositing out of the puddle as it dries up. "Enamel wear" of actual enamel is typically very slight to the point of not being an issue unless you are doing something massively abrasive in the tub, or the enamel isn't actual enamel..

Comment: NOTHING will be as good as the original enamel coating, period. Most of those DIY products explicitly state that it should not be used in a high traffic sink or tub.  Kitchen sink, forget about it! Main bathroom sink, nope! Powder room or half-bath sink which does not get used, go for it.

Comment: Have to also go with it being a stain.  Run a finger across the bottom, wear should feel like a slight dip, where a stain might feel a tiny bit raised.  This difference will be very, very slight and hard to tell.  The stain might be in the finish and be very hard to remove completely without damaging the enamel.

Answer (score 1):

I did not watch the entire video but have had my tub repainted. What they probably don't tell you is that you are supposed to completely dry the paint after each use. A pain! So most people don't do it , leave the tub very and afterwards have a peeling paint job in just a few years. I managed to make my last for 10 years, but I got tired of the drying. I've heard there are new paints. I personally would investigate tub liners, unless they offer a really long warranty on the paint.

Btw, diy paint kits are a disaster waiting to happen, IMHO.

Comment: ...and tub liners are vastly overpriced and chintzy. Replacing the tub makes far more sense than a tub liner, IMHO, IME.

Comment: And that's not practical if you have narrow hallways and doors, with lots of turns to bring in that heavy, new cast iron tub....sometimes you make choices based on what your existing situation is, level of demolition tolerated, timeframe, etc. So tub liners are a viable option. The ones you see at the big boxes have improved but the ones you can get installed by bath fitting companies are decent!